# PHP table that allows users to input height and width

Tags: php, html

[image: 9.2]

Hello. I have an assignment 9.2 to do and have no idea where to start.
I have made the index.php which allows the user to input the width and height of the table. 
Here is the code for that:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Assignment 9.2</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="black" text="white">
    <form method="post" action="table.php"
        <strong>Please select an integer for the width:</strong>
        <input type="text" name="width" size="10">
        <br>
        <strong>Please select an integer for the height:
        <input type="text" name="width" size="10">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I do not know where to start on making the table. I do not expect to have this
done for me.. but to simply explain where to start and the php codes I need to use. 
Again.. this is for 9.2 which is shown in the picture attached.

Comment: whoops. The name of the input box for height is "height". That was an error on my part.

Comment: Also.. any links for tutorials over this will help too!

Comment: Here you go http://php.net

Comment: Check out the html table examples and lessons http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so this is a fairly simple thing to do if you understand how `html` tables are laid out in code...

## HTML table format

The first step is to understand how tables are laid out in `html`...

### 3x2 table

For a 3 columned / 2 rowed table the code would look something like this...

#### Pseudo

```
opening table tag
    opening row tag
         cell tag
         cell tag
         cell tag
    closing row tag
    opening row tag
         cell tag
         cell tag
         cell tag
    closing row tag
closing table tag
```

#### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
     </tr>
</table>
```

I don't know how much you know about `html` but hopefully that should make sense if not there are a wide variety of resources available that can explain the *tags* used etc...

## PHP Code

At this point we're going to skip the input of width and height (as you already have the code for that) and assume that you've captured them as follows:

```
$in_width  = $_POST['width'];
$in_height = $_POST['height'];
```

So now we know what the width and height of the table is going to be we can look at how to put them together:

If you look back at the example *table code* above you'll see that `table`s are rendered one row at a time in the format:

- First row first column
- First row second column
- First row third column
- Second row first column
- ...and so on...

This might be more clear by looking at the numbers in your screen grab above.

Given that we know how a `html` table is structured we can determine that we can use two loops* (the second one embedded in the first) to produce the desired output.

(The *rows* will be the outer loop and the *columns* will be in the inner loop - see example `html` code above)

#### Pseudo code

```
start table
for each row {
   start row
   for each column {
       print cell
   }
   end row
}
end table
```

*You can use any loop you're comfortable with (i.e. for or loop) they do the same thing

If you want to do this yourself, I suggest that you stop reading here. **Spoiler** follows...

---

---

### Spoiler

#### Two `while` loops

```
$in_height  = $_POST['height'];   // Get table height
$in_width   = $_POST['width'];    // Get table width
$counter    = 1;                  // Start the counter at 1
$temp_width = 0;                  // Set temporary variable for width(second loop)

echo "<table>";              // Print opening tag for table
while($in_height > 0){
    echo "<tr>";             // Print opening tag for row
    $temp_width = $in_width; // Set temp_width to width of table
    while($temp_width > 0){
        echo "<td>$counter</td>";  // Print cell with counter value
        ++$counter;                // Increment counter
        --$temp_width;             // Decrement temp_width
    }
    echo "</tr>";  // Print closing tag for row
    --$in_height;  // Decrement height
}
echo "</table>";   // Print closing tag for table
```

#### Two `for` loops

Just for demonstration purposes...

```
$in_height   = $_POST['height'];
$in_width    = $_POST['width'];
$counter     = 1;
$temp_width  = 0;
$temp_height = 0;


echo "<table>";
for($temp_height = 0; $temp_height < $in_height; $temp_height++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for($temp_width = 0; $temp_width < $in_width; $temp_width++){
        echo "<td>$counter</td>";
        ++$counter;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

You could also mix and match loops...